# Is there a BPMN painter compatible with viewflow?

Tags: django, bpmn, viewflow

I want to integrate `D` with my existing Django application and want a graphical `BPMN` painter that my users can use to build workflows for `viewflow`.

Someone recommended "flow designer", but that appears to be dedicated to service now.  Another person recommended `CWL`,but I could find no supporting information.

The `viewflow` demo lists 'material' but that too doesn't quite fit.

So if someone knows a `BPMN` painter that is compatible with `viewflow`